# php mysql query form send value to other page

Tags: php, mysql

i have troublesome  with mysql query form
here's my code example

```
    <?
    $query="select * from data where  data_id=".$data_id."  order by data_id desc";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while ($dataresult=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   
    ?>

   <form style="display:table-row-group" id="form_data" name="form_data" action="view/view_data"  method="get" >
   <input type="hidden" name="ref" id="ref" value="hv" readonly />
   <input type='hidden' name='dataid' id='dataid' value='<? echo"$dataresult[data_id]"?>' readonly />

    <?
    echo" name = $dataresult[name] <br> 
         <button class=buttonimage onclick=$('#form_data').submit() type=button >Pesan</button>";
     ?>

    </form>
    <?
     }
     ?>
```

example printscreen   :   name : john
                           button select
                           name  : merry
                           button select

and the output i want like this is one selected : you selected name john idnumber

but it's not working it's always show end of id from query example if i select name john but the result show name merry

any one can help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quete on couple of places around `name` and change your `echo` `button` part as well.

```
echo" name =". $dataresult['name'].'<br>'; 
echo "<button class=buttonimage onclick=$('#form_data').submit() type=button >Pesan</button>";

<input type='hidden' name='dataid' id='dataid' value='<? echo"$dataresult[data_id]"?>' readonly />
<input type='hidden' name='dataid' id='dataid' value='<? echo"$dataresult['data_id']"?>' readonly />//Use this
```

and use the `php` tag like this

```
<?php //Opening tag

?> //Closing tag
```

Also use `mysqli_` function or `PDO` As `mysql` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code to work properly:

```
<?php
$query="select * from data where data_id=".$data_id."  order by data_id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($dataresult=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) // You can use _array also but this one is preferred if using only keys
{   
?>
<form style="display:table-row-group" id="form_data" name="form_data" action="view/view_data"  method="get" >
<input type="hidden" name="ref" id="ref" value="hv" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="hidden" name="dataid" id="dataid" value="<?php echo $dataresult['data_id']; ?>"  readonly="readonly" />
<?php echo "name=".$dataresult['name']; ?> <br />
<button class="buttonimage" onclick="$('#form_data').submit();" type="button">Pesan</button>
</form>
<?php 
 }
 ?>
```